# Sending cookies to client with express not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, cookies

My current setup is a Node.js app set up on Heroku, which is supposed to set some cookies for my client (a React app) using Express.js like this.

```
request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

    const access_token = body.access_token,
        refresh_token = body.refresh_token;



    let options = {
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
      json: true
    };
request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
             res.cookie('access_token',access_token, { domain: 'example.com', path: '/', expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9000000), httpOnly: false });
            res.cookie('refresh_token',refresh_token,{ domain: 'example.com', path: '/', expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9000000), httpOnly: false });
            res.cookie('user',body.display_name,{ domain: 'example.com', path: '/', expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9000000), httpOnly: false });

        res.redirect('https://www.example.com/');
     });
} else {...}}
```

It does set the cookies, but only in the Heroku app. The domain I give is ignored completely, which obviously results in an error when I try to read the cookies on the client side. Any advice?

Edit: Added the full function.

Comment: The cookies will be set on the domain of the original request and will NOT be available on a separate domain you might redirect to (for security reasons).  You will have to set 3rd party cookies if you're trying to set cookies for a different domain and hope the browser is configured to allow 3rd party cookies.  Google 3rd party cookies to see what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some very simplified working code to demonstrate cookie setting in a response to a network request:

```
const express = require('express')
const rp = require('request-promise-native')
const app = express();

app.get("/cookie", function(req, res) {
    rp.get('https://mobilesecurity.win/sample/access_token.json').then(function(body) {
        const domain = 'localhost';
        const parsed = JSON.parse(body);
        const access_token = parsed.access_token;
        const refresh_token = parsed.refresh_token;
        res.cookie('access_token',access_token, { domain: domain, path: '/', expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9000000), httpOnly: false });
        res.cookie('refresh_token',refresh_token,{ domain: domain, path: '/', expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9000000), httpOnly: false });
        res.status(200).json({'status':'cookies set!'})
    }).catch(function(error) {
        res.status(500).json({'status':'failure', error:error.message});
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Here's the result:

[image: Chrome cookie result]

Note here that I used `localhost` as the domain since I am running the server locally.  You must use a domain that matches your hostname, or the browser will refuse to set the cookie (for security reasons).